# WinApi Color Listbox

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I am trying to modify the color of items in my `Listbox`.
I use `WinApi C++` in `Visual Studio 2017`.
To create my `listbox`, I wrote that code:

```
hListbox = CreateWindowW(L"Listbox", L"My Listbox", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | LBS_EXTENDEDSEL, 100, 60, 300, 2400, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Add the items:

```
SendMessage(hListbox, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)Text); (...)
```

Is it possible to change the color of the text or the background, without changing the type of my object? Or is there an other easy way to create a `listbox` with colored items?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you have to draw it yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/create-an-owner-drawn-list-box

Comment: Is there a way? yes. Is there an easy way? It depends what you call easy :)

Comment: Thank you for your Link Swordfish.I will try to draw it myself. 
I asked for an easy way without drawing it, like I have it at the moment.

Comment: You could solve my problem.I have modified my code to draw the listbox myself. Now I can change the color of the text and the background.
Thank you :) !!